# DNS resolution fallback to NS

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I have a very basic question regarding DNS resolution rules.

Let's say that I my domain name is `mydomain.parentdomain.com` and I am having `bind` config (very stripped one):

```
               NS       ns.parentdomain.com

ORIGIN mydomain.parentdomain.com.
@              A        XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
www            CNAME    mydomain.parentdomain.com.
```

Given the case above, I have some questions (more of assumptions) to which I don't know the answers:

1. user visiting either `www` or `non-www` would resolve the `IP`. Correct?
2. if I remove both `A` and `CNAME`, users would not be able to resolve and would fallback to `ns.parentdomain.com` for resolution attempt. In my case, `ns.parentdomain.com` would have no idea about my domain, so no resolution would be possible. Correct?
3. Finally, leaving `A` and `CNAME` removed, but swaping my `NS` for `CloudFlare` `NS`, (it has a complete `DNS` configuration, all domains and subdomains), would this still work? I guess, the question is, would my original `DNS` server fallback to `CloudFlare` `NS` at all? If this is true, would this mean that I deferred a resolution completely to `CloudFlare`?

If I wasn't very clear or did leave some blanks in my question, please ask away in the comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will replace `parentdomain.com` with `example.com` which is reserved for documenting cases like this.

1. Only `mydomain.example.com` and `www.mydomain.example.com` will resolve. `non-www.mydomain.com` will not resolve as it isn't defined.
2. Unless `example.com` designates other name servers for `mydomain.example.com`, its name servers will be used to resolve `mydomain.example.com`.  Unless the domain is misconfigured there will be at least two name servers such as `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`.  However, the name server could just as well belong to another domain such as  `ns1.example.net` and `ns2.example.net`.  (Note: `.net` rather than `.com`.)  The NS record you have is redundant and likely incorrect.
3. Just configuring `CloudFlare` or any other name server will not work.  In this case `example.com` would need `NS` records for `mydomain.example.com` pointing to the `CloudFlare` name servers.

With no cached records the search will follow this order:

- Ask a root server for `www.mydomain.example.com` which will return the nameservers for `com`.
- Ask a `com` nameserver fo `www.mydomain.example.com` which will return the name servers for `example.com`.
- Ask an `example.com` nameserver for `www.mydomain.example.com` which will return data for `www.mydomain.example.com`.

If `mydomain.example.com` has been delegates other nameservers such as `CloudFlare` replace the last step with.

- Ask an `example.com` nameserver for `www.mydomain.example.com` which will return nameservers for `mydomain.example.com`.
- Ask an `mydomain.example.com` nameserver for `www.mydomain.example.com` which will return data for `www.mydomain.example.com`.

Comment: Exactly the type of explanation I needed :) Thanks a lot! :)